# WCAG and screen readers - Label a <section> with an <h> tag, and not have the label read twice

Tags: html, wai-aria, wcag2.0

I've been bringing some sites into WCAG 2.1 AA compliance.  In the interest of having easy navigation, I've separated page content into relevant <section> tags, and also provided an <h> tag, to allow screen readers to navigate both through landmarks and headers.  I then use the <h> as a label for the <section>, using aria-labelledby.  Problem is, at least in Chrome with NVDA, when navigating by landmarks or headers it reads out the label twice.  If I remove aria-labelledby from the <section>, it skips the section.

Am I being overzealous with my labeling, or is some redundancy to be expected?  I don't want to remove the <h> tags (which are hidden visually and just for screen readers), as maybe some people prefer to navigate through headers.

I could move the <h> to the bottom of the <section>, and then NVDA just reads the first line of actual content.  That would sort of work, but I don't love structuring the DOM like that. (Plus then screen readers encounter the header at the bottom, which is confusing.)

Is there a way to have a label only read once, when it's the first piece of content in a <section> it's labeling?

Comment: If you are using aria-labelledby, the screenreader will read that label and then it will read the physical <h> tag.  I don't know a way you could conditionally skip the <h> when it is being read by sections and skip the <section> when traveling through headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have something like this?

```
<section aria-labelledby="h2id">
  <h2 id="h2id">hello</h2>
  <!-- other stuff -->
</section>
```

When I navigate by landmarks with NVDA (<kbd>D</kbd> key), **both** Chrome and Firefox will say *"hello region, hello, heading level 2"*

Similarly, if I navigate by headings (<kbd>H</kbd> key), I'll hear the same thing.

That's strange.

If I inspect the accessibility tree in Chrome's devtools, the <section> shows:

```
Name: "hello"
  aria-labelledby: "hello"
  aria-label: Not specified
  title: Not specified
Role: region
Labeled by:
```

So that looks correct.  The accessible name of the landmark is just "hello", which is exactly what the "[Accessible Name and Description Computation 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2)" says it should be.  I'm not sure why the heading is also read.

The same problem exists with VoiceOver on iOS.  Both the region and heading are read when I navigate by landmarks or headings (via the rotor).

I don't have JAWS but if you have access to it, try it there too.

I would leave it alone.  The html seems correct.  A little extra verbosity is probably ok given the advantage of navigating by landmarks and headings.